# HTML Canvas Functions from Select Option

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to create a a simple html page that displays a canvas with a background as a college map. There is a dropdown list and the user can select a room they are trying to get too and lines will be displayed on the canvas depending on which room is selected.

I am trying to call these different lines depending on the selection but am struggling to find why this is not working

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<div>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
canvas, img { display:block; margin:1em auto; border:1px solid black; }
canvas { background:url(pretendcollege.jpg) }
  </style>
<canvas id="c4" width="580" height = "580" ></canvas>
<div>

  <select   name="rooms" onchange="path(this.value)">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="B223">B223</option>
  <option value="C174">C174</option>
  <option value="B170">B170</option>
</select>

</div> 
</div>

<script>
var c4 = document.getElementById("c4");
var c4_context = c4.getContext("2d");

function path(v) {
  switch(v) {
    case "B220":
    c4_context.beginPath();
    c4_context.moveTo(295, 473);
    c4_context.lineTo(295, 286);
    c4_context.lineTo(94, 286);
    c4_context.strokeStyle = "Red";
    c4_context.stroke();
  break;
case "C174":
  c4_context.beginPath();
    c4_context.moveTo(295, 473);
    c4_context.lineTo(295, 82);
    c4_context.lineTo(118, 82);
    c4_context.strokeStyle = "Blue";
    c4_context.stroke();
  break;
}
}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issues may be coming from when you call your JS. You want to grab the canvas tag and it's context *after* you create it in your html, yet you want to put the entire script *before* you call the path() function. Here is working code:

=== EDITED ===

yourHtmlFile.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body>
       <div>
           <canvas id="c4" width="580" height="580" ></canvas>
            <select name="rooms" onchange="path(this.value)">
                <option value="">Please select</option>
                <option value="B223">B223</option>
                <option value="C174">C174</option>
                <option value="B170">B170</option>
            </select>
       </div> 
       <script src="yourOtherScript.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

yourOtherScript.js

```
var c4 = document.getElementById("c4");
var c4_context = c4.getContext("2d");

function path(v) {
    switch(v) {
        case "B220":
            c4_context.beginPath();
            c4_context.moveTo(295, 473);
            c4_context.lineTo(295, 286);
            c4_context.lineTo(94, 286);
            c4_context.stroke();
            break;
        case "C174":
            c4_context.beginPath();
            c4_context.moveTo(295, 473);
            c4_context.lineTo(295, 82);
            c4_context.lineTo(118, 82);
            c4_context.stroke();
            break;
    }
}
```

Check out my fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/9m7bjhqt/)

Comment: I caught myself thanks to the down vote. One shouldn't have to grab the canvas and the context EVERY TIME you call the function. You can mitigate this by calling the script after the body has loaded (put the script tags after the content) or by using something like JQuery's $(document).ready(). I will update the answer to reflect this.